# PHP MySQL Insert Query From Multiple Tables into two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I've table like this :

```
tb_users
id, name, pin_number

tb_attendance
pin, date_time, user_id
```

i've created simple query for tb_attendace like this :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tb_attendance 
        ( pin, date_time) 
        values 
        ('$PIN', '$DateTime')";
```

i want to insert colum user_id from tb_users where tb_users.pin_number = tb_attendance.pin

in mysql command i've success run this :

```
INSERT INTO tb_attendance (pin, date_time, entry_by)
SELECT  pin, date_time, tb_users.id
FROM    tb_attendance , tb_users
WHERE   tb_attendance.pin = tb_users.pin_number
```

but i don't know how to create this query into php script.
can some one help me to complete the php script ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need both the `pin` and user id, if you can just use `JOIN` to get the `PIN`.

The query that you want looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tb_attendance (pin, date_time, entry_by)
    SELECT $PIN, $DATE_TIME, u.id
    FROM tb_users u
    WHERE u.pin_number = $PIN;
```

I would advise you to use query parameters, and not to insert the parameter values directly into the SQL string.  That is dangerous -- both in terms of creating a SQL syntax error and in terms of security.

Comment: PIN will be execute in my next query, but before insert into the table, the column PIN must match with values from tb_users.pin_number. the ID from tb_users in laravel as entry_by